# QueryDslPredicateExecutor Q-class is not generating

Tags: maven, querydsl

My Pom file is

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6</version>
        </dependency> 
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6</version>
        </dependency> 

<plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

After adding those dependency and plugin in pom.xml, I ran mvn clean install, QAutoManifest is not generating. I am new to jpa, Please help me.

```
public interface AutoManifestRepository extends CrudRepository<AutoManifest,String>,QueryDslPredicateExecutor<AutoManifest>{
}
```

And my Predicate class is

```
public class AutoManifestPredicate {
    private AutoManifestPredicate() {
        System.out.println("Predicate Object gets created");
    }
    static Predicate searchAutoManifest(SearchAutoManifest manifest) {


        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: please show the AutoManifest class, including imports.